# How to know which p-dropdown has triggered the event

Tags: angular, primeng

I've two `p-dropdowns` inside a `formGroup` and both are calling the same generic method.

```
<!-- Fruit List -->
<p-dropdown
  (onChange)="callMethod($event)"
  ...
>
</p-dropdown>

<!-- Vegetable List -->
<p-dropdown
  (onChange)="callMethod($event)"
  ...
>
</p-dropdown>
```

Notice that both are calling the same `callMethod` method. How can I distinguish between these two dropdowns inside my method. I didn't get a single content for the same on the internet. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to add another parameter to `callMethod` and pass the list name as an argument.

```js
callMethod($event, listType: string) {

 switch(listType){
   case 'fruitList': {
     ...
     break;
   }
   case 'vegetableList': {
     ...
     break;
   }
 }
}
```

```html
<!-- Fruit List -->
<p-dropdown
  (onChange)="callMethod($event, 'fruitList')"
  ...
>
</p-dropdown>

<!-- Vegetable List -->
<p-dropdown
  (onChange)="callMethod($event, 'vegetableList')"
  ...
>
</p-dropdown>
```